# Counting a SQL result

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I select data with `group by`

```
select rkey from asset group by rkey
```

this will give me:

```
 ADATUM 
 BEZ1
 KLASSE
 AWERT
 ANLNR
 LOCATION
 BEZ2
 BKRS
 UNR
```

now, how can I count the result, so that I get (9). If it works, in one SELECT Statement.

Comment: Try using the count() function!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT COUNT(rkey)
FROM
(
  select rkey from asset group by rkey
) t
```

Or, you can get rid of the `GROUP BY` and use `DISTINCT` instead, because the inner query with `select rkey from asset group by rkey` is acting like `DISTINCT`. So you can do it in one query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT rkey) 
FROM asset
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `distinct`

```
select count(distinct rkey) 
from asset
```